# Model accuracy not improving in CNN for image classification

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, resnet

I am using ResNext architecture for classification. the training dataset contains approximately 31000 images distributed among 61 classes. And validation dataset contains appx. 4500 images. but unfortunately the training accuracy is not increasing over 13%, can any one show me what am I doing wrong here?

[Code is here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1v3kYeGbp8gPgipir8hVIZsVK8w94xI8q?usp=sharing)

[Model architecture](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BuXM7dsZWZxc_6W30XqYLBSNaNZ540Bb?usp=sharing)

[Data Loader](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1o3zXzE_PwEaVrqkSwXuO_yjO3OjWxHrE?usp=sharing)

[Resnext research paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.05431.pdf)

With this data set 90% accuracy have achieved with inception resnet v2 model, and this in the research paper of resnext, it is claiming it should perform better than inception resnet v2 model. So I am expecting accuracy better than this.

Comment: Are you doing any data augmentation?  I noticed this line in your linked paper which makes me think some augmentation should be going on - "On the ImageNet
dataset, the input image is 224×224 randomly cropped
from a resized image using the scale and aspect ratio augmentation of [38] implemented by [11]"

Comment: yes, I am resizing image in 224x224, you can refer to the data loader file, that I have attached.

Comment: Resizing images is not the same thing as data augmentation.  Perhaps I'm missing it, but I don't see any data augmentation in your code or the data loader.  I don't think it would account for all the difference you are seeing, but it might get you above 13% accuracy.

Comment: @inteoryx can you show me what can be done for data augmentation?

Comment: I think you will want to use data augmentation in [Keras as described here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/data_augmentation).  As I quoted in my previous comment the paper you are working from uses the data augmentation strategies described in those two other papers.  I haven't looked those up to see what their strategies are - but that seems like a reasonable thing to do.

As I mentioned, I wouldn't expect this will completely solve your problem, but I would expect it to help.